# Query on SQL Server Reporting Services Database, ReportServer.Catalog table to analyze report parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, xquery

I am trying to write a query that pulls out the names of all of the parameters in my report server. The parameters data is stored as XML in an ntext field so I don't think I can use xquery on it.

What I initially started doing was making case statements for each parameter name I expect to find but, this is going to be tedious and I don't think the report developers were totally consistent with parameter names (and in fact that is one of my reasons for wanting the query).

Here is what i have so far, which is pretty simplistic:

```
SELECT [Path], [Name], CreationDate, ModifiedDate, Parameter, 
CASE WHEN Parameter LIKE '%<Name>UserId</Name>%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS  'UserId', 
CASE WHEN Parameter LIKE '%<Name>Country</Name>%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Country',
CASE WHEN Parameter LIKE '%<Name>Office</Name>%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Office'
FROM dbo.Catalog
WHERE type IN (2, 4)
AND [path] NOT LIKE '/Enterprise Reports%' 
AND [Path] NOT LIKE '/Email Subscription%'
ORDER BY [Path]
```

What I think I want is something more like this:

```
SELECT [Path], [Name], CreationDate, ModifiedDate, Parameter.query(/Parameters/Parameter/Name)
FROM dbo.Catalog
WHERE type IN (2, 4)
AND [path] NOT LIKE '/Enterprise Reports%' 
AND [Path] NOT LIKE '/Email Subscription%'
ORDER BY [Path]
```

The problem is, it's ntext, not xml. Can I just use convert on that?

The other problem is, I don't know the xquery syntax to pull out the name field of the many parameters within the XML.

The document's schema is very simple:

```
<Parameters>
   <Parameter>
      <Name>Some name</Name>
      ...some more fields i don't care about...
   </Parameter>
   <Parameter>
      <Name>Another name</Name>
   </Parameter>
   ...more parameters, etc.
</Parameters>
```

I just want a list of what is in the names.

There can be many  nodes and each one has a single  node as a child.

UPDATE:

It seems like Nodes() should help me but I am struggling to take the examples on Books Online and a Simple Talk article and apply it to my situation. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT [Path], [Name], CreationDate, ModifiedDate, Parameter, 
CASE WHEN Parameter LIKE '%<Name>UserId</Name>%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'UserId', 
CASE WHEN Parameter LIKE '%<Name>Country</Name>%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Country',
CASE WHEN Parameter LIKE '%<Name>Office</Name>%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Office'
, CAST(Parameter AS XML).nodes('/Parameters/Parameter/Name')
FROM dbo.Catalog
WHERE type IN (2, 4)
AND [path] NOT LIKE '/Enterprise Reports%' 
AND [Path] NOT LIKE '/Email Subscription%'
ORDER BY [Path]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is: yes, it's as easy as a CONVERT(xml, Parameter). Assuming that it's well formed XML, it'll convert just fine

The second question is going to involve the nodes() method of the XML data type. Read all about it: [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx).

***Edit:***

Now that I'm in a position to test, here's what I came up with:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT   CAST(parameter AS XML) AS parameter
    FROM     [dbo].[Catalog] AS c
)
SELECT  p.value('(./Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
FROM    cte AS c
CROSS APPLY c.Parameter.nodes('/Parameters/Parameter') AS T ( p )
```

Comment: Yeah, I am messing with nodes right now but all of the examples don't seem to apply. I am looking at the BOL page for it and a really good Simple Talk article. I will post what I have so far...

Comment: I'm far from an XML wizard, but it's going to be something like: select p.value('./Name', 'nvarchar(50)') from dbo.Catalog as c cross apply c.Parameter.nodes('/Parameters/Parameter') at T(p)

Comment: I am trying to use COALESCE to comma separate the parameter names so there is only one row per report. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: More XML shenanigans. It's a bit beyond the scope of this question. Ask another and I'll be glad to help you there.